# synchronize videos with same time line

Tags: video

I'm looking for the easiest way to synchronize two video vertically (mp4) and to play them at the same time and with the same timecode. I tried adobe premiere but it didn't support the weight of each video (700 Mo * 2) I need high resolution.

Until now I'm using VLC and play each video in one side but it is not practical because when I want to go back 10 second I do each few times in both video.

I tried also virtualdub with AviSynth_260 by creating an avs file :

```
vid1 = directshowsource("C:\Utilisateurs\folder\1.mp4")
vid2= directshowsource("C:\Utilisateurs\folder\2.mp4")
StackHorizontal(vid1,vid2)
```

Have error : AVI Import Filter error: (Unknown) 80040154. So also virtualdubd don't work for me.

Is there any efficient, easy way : **software**  ? thanks

Comment: You can use VLC on a webpage?

Comment: How ? The aim is to have one play button for both two video to synchroize them. Once one is activated at 0.09s for example, the second should be activated also at this time. Thanks

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Sorry you're talking software, I think I got something...

Comment: Try [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/2650/16659)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested Wax, with the split screen option. the only problem that it crop both video while I need them in their actual width / Height, or let's say 50% width height in order to display both video. I tried to manage crop option but it seems that the split is based on these values. It was almost what I needed but still full width and height is a paramount for me.

Comment: Are you using two separate monitors? Like a laptop and a flat screen plugged into it's HDMI?

Comment: No it is the same screen, and i tried to render the result so I've one video. Do you think that if I use two screen it could fix the issue ?

Comment: If your hardware is decent yes. If you have a desktop with a decent video card. There are video cards that allow you to use 2 to 6 monitors at a time.